# Select multiple rows using id in SQLite

Tags: sqlite, syntax-error, sqlfiddle

I am trying to query specific rows from my SQLite database using `WHERE` conditions on the IDs of the rows I want.  However, the query is not returning any results, and it is causing my logger to throw an error stating that there is a syntax error.

Here is the query:

```
Select * From Equipment Where ID = 2 and ID = 3 and ID = 4 and ID = 7 and ID = 11 and ID = 34
```

And here is the syntax error from my log:

```
Aug 17 2017 23:12:23  [Err]: Err002 - Query on Equipment could not be prepared: near "=": syntax error at File: c:\users\geowil\documents\visual studio 2015\projects\ov_pocs\universearc_poc\datasystem.cpp  Line: 323.
```

So I sailed over to [SQLFiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!5/68cd3f/4) to try and see if I missed something.  It is displaying the same behavior.  With `and` conditions, it returns no results - but running queries on single IDs or a range of IDs works.

Am I doing something wrong or is this a limitation of SQLite?

**Update:**

Had a brain wave.  Using `Where ID IN(1,3,4)` works on SQLFiddle so now I want to repurpose my question to ask why *this* works, but my original query did not.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Use `IN` to select your multiple tuples.

```
Select * From Equipment Where ID IN (2, 3, 4, 7, 11, 34);
```

Every tuple will be selected if every ids existed in your SQLite or Database.

---

For your query, your logical equation will never select one of the tuple because an id won't have two or more values (`ID=2 AND ID=3`: if `ID` equal to `2` it won't be equal to `3`). In your case you must use `OR` instead of `AND`.

```
Select * From Equipment Where ID=2 OR ID=3 OR ID=4 OR ID=7 OR ID=11 OR ID=34;
```

So that every tuple will be selected if every ids existed in your SQLite or Database.

Comment: Oh jesus.  Duh, don't know why that did not occur to me lol.  Thanks.

Comment: You are welcome!
Please help to check it as a correct answer!

Answer (score 1):

Use `IN` instead of `=` like, issue will be fixed:

```
SELECT * FROM Equipment WHERE ID IN (1 , 2);
```

Answer (score 1):

`AND` means that the conditions on both sides must be true. But for any single row, there can only be a single `ID` value.

To check for a match with any one of multiple values, replace `AND` with `OR`, or use `IN`.